# Conditional logic in the class property

Tags: c#

```
public class test
{
    public datetime date1 {get;set;}
    public datetime date2 {get;set;}
    public string status {get;set;}
}
```

Now the value of property status is calculated 
based on the values for date1 and date2

For example

```
if date1 > dataetime.today 
status ="active"
else
status = "inactive"
```

I think I need to write the logic in the set of the property status.
How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Sounds like `status` should be a read only property `public string status { get { return date1 > DateTime.Today ? "active" : "inactive"; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class test
{
    public datetime date1 {get;set;}
    public datetime date2 {get;set;}
    public string status {
        get{
            if (date1 > dataetime.today)
               return "active";
            else
               return "inactive" ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to always be synchronized with `date1` then you should make `status` a getter.

```
public string status
{
    get
    {
        return date1 > DateTime.Today ? "Active" : "Inactive";
    }
}
```

**Note:** I would strongly recomend you to follow [C# Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Status
{
    get
    {
        // your code
    }
    set
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

You can read more about get and set accessors [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx).